# Conditional Formatting And and Or

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I am trying to do some conditional formating with AND and OR.

I need to turn cell B2 red if cell B2 and C2, or D2. are filled.

So if cell B2 is filled in with text and either C2 or D2 then I need it to turn red

But, if only C2 and D2 are filled nothing will turn red

If cell B2 and C2 are filled then red

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
=And(B2<>"",OR(C2<>"",D2<>""))
```

Comment: @JordanArdakanian please mark as correct.  Only you can do that.  Click on the green check mark by the answer.  Also glad I could help.